# Trying to establish an internal connection with sockets between threads and connect fails

Tags: c, linux, sockets, polling, multiplexing

I am trying to create a local connection between threads of the same process using a socket of AF_INET family.
The server is supposed to handle clients and serve their requests via multiplexing with threads.

So at the server's main thread I have this for the external connection:
*(checking for errors is omitted for keeping the length of the post reasonable)*

```
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
struct sockaddr *serverptr=(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr;
listening_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
fds[0].fd = listening_sock;
fds[0].events = POLLIN;
// Setting listening socket
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
int one = 1;
setsockopt(listening_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void *)&one, sizeof(one));
setsockopt(listening_sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *)&one, sizeof(one));
bind(listening_sock, serverptr, sizeof(server_addr));
listen(listening_sock, 5);
```

and then using poll I am polling at the listening socket successfully (communicating with a client).

Now I want to create an internal socket via TCP for communication between the main thread and a new thread I'll create.
I've added these:

```
struct sockaddr_in loopback_addr;
struct sockaddr *loopbackptr=(struct sockaddr *)&loopback_addr;
loopback_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //checking for errors is omitted
fds[1].fd = loopback_sock;
fds[1].events = POLLIN;
// Setting loopback socket
loopback_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IN_LOOPBACKNET);
loopback_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
loopback_addr.sin_port = htons(18000);
int one = 1;
setsockopt(loopback_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void *)&one, sizeof(one));
setsockopt(loopback_sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *)&one, sizeof(one));
bind(loopback_sock, loopback_ptr, sizeof(loopback_addr));
listen(loopback_sock, 5);
```

And also increased the nfds counter to 2.
Now the thread starts before the loop of poll and tries to communicate with this code:

```
struct sockaddr_in server;
struct sockaddr *serverptr = (struct sockaddr*)&server;
int sock;
if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    perror("thread: socket");
    pthread_exit((void*)-1);
}

int port = 18000;
server.sin_family = AF_INET;      
server.sin_addr.s_addr = IN_LOOPBACKNET; 
server.sin_port = htons(port);        
if (connect(sock, serverptr, sizeof (server)) < 0)
{
    perror("thread: connect");
    pthread_exit((void*)-1);
}
```

And what happens is that connect syscall returns `thread: connect: Network is unreachable`.

At the server's main loop I have this:

```
if (fd[1].revents)
    printf("Loopback socket\n");
```

to check whether there is any interraction with this socket, but this never prints out anything.

I am not sure how to set up the internal socket, if there is a tutorial I could read, a link would be more than welcome!

It might be something simple, but as I am new to socket programming I cannot find it.

---

**Edit:**
After changing the IN_LOOPBACKNET to htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK) as alk proposed, connect still fails but with a new message, `connection refused`.
But still, there are no revents from the fds[2].

Comment: Didn't the server's call to `bind()` gave you an error?

Comment: @alk: Nope, no error there :/ There must be something wrong with the 2nd block of code I've posted. The server handles just fine the "external" communication by a client. But getting a connection refused from internal socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message (`Network is unreachable`) you could have conclude that there is something fishy with addressing.

So you might like to change

```
IN_LOOPBACKNET
```

to be

```
INADDR_LOOPBACK
```

The former resolves to `127` which most likely is not what you want, as it's the local loopback network.

The latter suits better as it resolves to `0x7f000001`, which ist the integer representation of the loopback address `127.0.0.1`.

---

Also you are missing the conversion to network byte order (`htonl()`) when assigning the ip-address the client shall connect to.

Comment: I was trying to find out what happened and I used gethostbyname as I am using it with my client app giving it as an argument "localhost" and it worked, giving me a `connection refused`. Now, I've updated the code with what you've posted me and still getting the `connection refused` without any print from the server's main loop.

Comment: @Chris: You are not showing the part of the server's sources which does actually waits for connections to come in, but you are aware that a call to `accept()` is needed to do so, aren't you? `Connection refused` simply tells the client that there is noone waiting to `accept()` a connection on the address:port you are trying to connect.

Comment: Yes alk, I know that we need accept. The problem was the address of the localhost at the server. If you notice, it's IN_LOOPBACKNET while it should be INADDR_LOOPBACK. Thank you for your help! Also, could you please answer me this, should ALL numbers that are sent over the network be converted with htonl/s ?

Comment: @Chris: Yuo might like to also show the code involving `accept()`. And: Did you also correct the server sources regarding the wrong use of `IN_LOOPBACKNET`?

Comment: Yes I did, it now works perfectly. Should I update my code here?

Comment: @Chris: No leave the code as it, so it is possible for others to understand what we wre talking about. I undid you **update** therefore.